# communication between two emulators through server pc as middle man

Tags: c#, android, .net

i want to built an application which is communication network between two emulator. i have already connect emulator with server.

Now i want to connect two emulators through server(C#) which is PC. like we sent sms through mobile networks.

I need guidance to start this.

Comment: Create a Web Service for same :)

Comment: is web service is important cannot we build tcp server. i do not want to go for web service any other solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your requirements are and how far you would go to implement best practices, however, here are some points to consider based on my experience on a similar application, just to make it clear we worked on a solution where many Android phones would connect to a server to send/receive data.

Web Service is the way to go, this is what web services are meant for, we created WCF based APIs for the applications connecting to the server.

You are working on a heterogeneous system Java on Android, C# on the Server, consider creating REST based APIs on the server for data transfer

Go through these to get a feel of what needs to be done onthe server...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

And this for what needs to be done at Android side...
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/consuming_web_services

hope that helps....